# Ping a Domain-Name-Server from a Network

Tags: networking

I set up a Domain name Inside of the /etc/hosts file and I enabled ICMP requests

What I'm wanting to do is ping my Domain Name that's inside of /etc/hosts, I can ping it from my machine, but i cant ping it from anywhere in my network or outside of my network

I tried setting port forwarding in the router on port 53 to my machine, but that didn't allow any pings either, Do i need to set up iptables/ route or something to 192.168.1.142 ( My IP ), I mean how can I ping 8.8.8.8 if it isn't in my /etc/resolv.conf file

I'm trying to ping cheese.com which is my domain name, I can ping 192.168.1.142 but I cant ping cheese.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want other machines to be able to ping your domain, you need to set the domain and its ip address in a DNS server that is visible and accessible globally. for example you can use ns1.com or cloudflare.com DNS service. 
The /etc/hosts file is only accessible from your computer.

Comment: Isn't there a route command I could use for the hosts on my network, or should iptables be used

Comment: @hellomotto for hostname -> IP address, no, routes won't help you here.  You need to be able to identify an IP address from the hostname, and that requires a DNS server to be in place.  Editing /etc/hosts will *not* provide a DNS server that can be queried globally by your network, and editing resolv.conf won't help either.